interrater reliability on multiple columns
How does one check for interrater reliability when one is asked to run a qualitative analyses where each statement may tap into various themes? e.g.,
why do you like gardening:
Coder 1:



Participant's response
theme 1 - exercise
theme 2 - relaxing
theme 3 - monetary theme
theme 4 - aesthetics




I like to garden because my house looks nicer and can sell some of the flowers
0
0
1
1


It's a nice form of exercise
1
0
0
0


Flowers are pretty
0
0
0
1



Coder 2:



Participant's response
theme 1 - exercise
theme 2 - relaxing
theme 3 - monetary theme
theme 4 - aesthetics




I like to garden because my house looks nicer and can sell some of the flowers
0
0
1
0


It's a nice form of exercise
1
0
0
0


Flowers are pretty
0
0
0
1



How can we calculate the overall agreement across all themes and all participants between these coders? I know this is a silly example, I just wanted to be able to demonstrate what I mean. I use R for data analysis.
